# Where can I store an access token object to be available in the application in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0

I am retrieving an access_token object in order to authenticate my application.

```
qb_access_token = quickbooks_credentials.access_token
qb_refresh_token = quickbooks_credentials.refresh_token

access_token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(oauth2_client, qb_access_token, refresh_token: qb_refresh_token)
```

Where is the right place to store this information and have it available in controllers and models?

Comment: Is it an access token for a specific user of your application or is it an access token for your entire application?

Comment: It's for the entire application.

Comment: Memcached/Redis or rails low-level caching would be one place. I don't think you really want to pass this to your models *ever* as they should not be doing HTTP requests or be aware of a 3-rd party API. Models already have way to many responsibilities - instead you want to create clients and service objects that talk to the API.

Comment: The same goes for controllers. They are notoriously hard to test and fat controllers is a particularly bad code smell. The more you can isolate code that touches an application boundry the better.